# Cloning items into connected list that allow duplicates using angular ui-sortable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

I am working on drag n drop functionality using [angular-ui-sortable](/questions/tagged/angular-ui-sortable). I am using connected list example provided [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) in GitHub repo.

In list#1 I have list of HTML controls and list#2 is empty. By default when I drag any item from list#1 it will remove from list#1 and add in list#2. I do not want to remove it from the list instead a copy of it adds in list#2. And list#2 items cannot be dragged back on list#1.

Here is my code

```html
<div class="floatleft">
  <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="apps-container screen floatleft" ng-model="list1">
    <div class="app" ng-repeat="app in list1">{{$index}} {{app.title}}</div>
  </div>
  <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="apps-container screen floatleft" ng-model="list2">
    <div class="app" ng-repeat="app in list2">{{$index}} {{app.title}}</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$scope.list1 = [{
  name: 'Checkbox'
}, {
  name: 'text'
}, {
  name: 'email'
}, ]

$scope.list2 = [];
$scope.sortableOptions = {
  placeholder: "app",
  connectWith: ".apps-container"
};
```

Need help how do I achieve that.

Comment: What do you mean *"And list#2 items cannot be dragged back on list#2."*?

Comment: Means list#2 item sortable option to another list should be cancel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow duplicates, you should use `track by $index` in the second list's `ng-repeat`.

---

For cloning you should do the following in `update` callback:

```
update: function(e, ui) {
    if(ui.item.sortable.isCanceled()) return;
    ui.item.sortable.cancel();
    var model = angular.copy(ui.item.sortable.model);
    ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel.splice(ui.item.sortable.dropindex, 0, model);
  }
```

---

finally, to disable sorting from list#2 to list#1, you should use different options for list#2 without the `connectWith` property. Or make the `connectWith` value unique, something which is not applicable to list#1. (If you look at the below demo I'm deleting `connectWith` from options for second list)

### [**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRpVPO?editors=0010#anon-login)

Comment: One problem in your solution is that if I drag list#2 up and down it creates new element ?? how to solve it ?

Comment: I have solved it by putting a check 
 if (_listName != 'B') {
                            ui.item.sortable.cancel();
                            var model = angular.copy(ui.item.sortable.model);
                            ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel.splice(ui.item.sortable.dropindex, 0, model);
                        }